# Ant deployment throwing error "The version of the flow you're updating was active and can't be overwritten"

Tags: deployment, process-builder, visual-workflow, ant

I am trying to migrate all Process builders from one instance to other, the target instance already has few flows available which are active.I inactivated all of them and trying to deploy the package which has flows and flow definitions.

Even when the flows are inactive the deployment is failing giving below error.

```
The version of the flow you're updating was active and can't be overwritten.
```

I cross checked all the flows in the error list all of them were in Inactive state, is there any step I am missing while deploying the flows?

Answer (score 2):

Go through the below link. It contains information you are looking for 
[Getting an error that a flow "was" activate and cannot be overwritten](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92130/getting-an-error-that-a-flow-was-activate-and-cannot-be-overwritten)

Answer (score 0):

The ability to do this does actually exist but you have to request it and they STRONGLY caution you about it for the same reasons as listed in the post RedDevil pointed you to. The way to do it is outlined here in [Deployment issues with Process Builder Flows](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81657/deployment-issues-with-process-builder-flows)