# Continuous Integration with Metadata API and flow/processes deployment

Tags: metadata-api, flow, ci, process

**Duplicated**: Please see [Flows/Processes, Version Control and CI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61617/flows-processes-version-control-and-ci)

Using CI for deploying [flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm)/processes to the same environment results in error if existing version has been already activated:

```
flows/YYYY-1.flow -- Error: The version of the flow you're updating is active and can't be overwritten.
```

What is the best practice to use CI for flows deployment?

Comment: See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61617/flows-processes-version-control-and-ci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the metadata API will **not** let you deploy a flow or process to overwrite an active one. If you are in sandboxes and can use changesets, that's the best way to resolve this.

What CI tool are you using? You might be able to write a pre-deploy hook to deactivate any active flows/processes first.

Comment: Using deployment automation (jenkins, for example) you can create ANT scripts which could solve this kind of problems. Might be worth checking out. There are more metadata types which are not default supported through the metadata APi (like Entitlement Processes)